# google charts api get chart without element argument?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using a tool that creates google charts behind a facade. Works well, but now I'm adding diff charts.

Diff charts require access to chart.computeDiff(...) but this requires a chart, which in turn as far as I can see (for some reason) requires an argument referencing an html element. This doesn't conform to the flow of the tool I'm using.

Is there any other way to get access to the chart methods, or some other place to get access to computeDiff?

The tool uses

```
  this.wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(chartConfig);
```

for instance, but

```
 let chart = this.wrapper.getChart() just returns null
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

never mind, i took computeDiff from the appropriate prototypes:

```
let computeDiff = google.visualization[this.wrapper.getChartType()].prototype.computeDiff
        let chartDiff = computeDiff(oldData,newData)
    return chartDiff
```

seems to work